# How to sort a list so that the same changes would happen in another list?

Tags: c#, list

I have a question:
For example I have 2 lists:
1: `Banana` `Apple` `Orange`
2: `Yellow`  `Red` `Orange`

I want it to list.sort
so it will be:
`Apple` `Banana` `Orange`
But in the same time I want the SAME changes happening inside of the Yellow red orange list.
So it would be like this:
`Apple` `Banana` `Orange`
`Red`   `Yellow` `Orange`

I didnt try this because I literally have no idea how to do this and all this is just on the planning board

Comment: Don't have two lists of corresponding entities, have one list of Tuples ( not neccessarily C#/.NET Tuples, could also be a class or struct ... ). And then sort by one of the properties.

Answer (score 4):

You should really start using classes which encapsulate these information in one entity, for example:

```
public class Fruit
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Color {get; set;}
}
```

Then it's easy and readable:

```
List<Fruit> fruits = new()
{
    new Fruit{ Name = "Banana", Color = "Yellow" },
    new Fruit{ Name = "Apple", Color = "Red" },
    new Fruit{ Name = "Orange", Color = "Orange" }
};

var orderedFruits = fruits.OrderBy(f => f.Name);
```

If you want to sort the original list, simply append `ToList` ad re-assign it:

```
fruits = fruits.OrderBy(f => f.Name).ToList();
```

---

If you really must use two separate lists which depend on each other, you *could* use `Zip`:

```
List<string> fruitNames = new() { "Banana", "Apple", "Orange" };
List<string> fruitColors = new() { "Yellow", "Red", "Orange" };
List<(string Name, string Color)> orderedFruits = fruitNames
    .Zip(fruitColors, (n, c) => (Name: n, Color: c))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
    .ToList();
fruitNames = orderedFruits.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
fruitColors = orderedFruits.Select(x => x.Color).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason it is problematic to merge the lists, say you have a large list of large structs for example, an alternative can be to use a proxy list with indices for sorting:

```
var fruits = ...
var colors = ...
var proxy = Enumerable.Range(0, fruits.Length);
var sortedProxy = proxy.OrderBy(i => fruits[i]);
var sortedColors = sortedProxy.Select(i => colors[i]).ToList();
```

This lets you sort the indices according to the order defined by one list, and then you can use this ordering to create an ordered list for any list of the same length. Note that this example leaves the fruit list unordered.

You can reduce allocations by creating a custom comparer that does the `i => fruits[i]`-part so that you can use `List.Sort` instead of OrderBy.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to `zip` the two list, making a list of pairs.
Then you can apply a custom `sort` on this list of pair, sorting pairs only relatively to the first element.
Once the sort is done, you can `unzip` the list of pairs to get back your two lists, sorted the same way.

Comment: Having separate lists of otherwise corresponding data is a bad idea, anyways. Even Non-OOP languages would group those into structs or similar.

Comment: But you sometimes can't do much about some data you receive from other interfaces. He asked how to do some arbitrary operation, I gave the answer ^^